# Return all relationship data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-eloquent-resource

I want to retrieve data using eloquent model and return it in the following json response.

```
user[
     transactions[],
     clients[
            ubications[],
            contactos[],
            plans[],
      ]
]
```

Currently I am receiving user,transcation and clients data but I am not able to retreive the data inside client property e.g ubications[],contactos[] and plans[].So I need help regarding the sub properties as I have already implemented the relationship.

Here are the models I am using 

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function token(){
        return $this->access_token;
    }
    public function transaction(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
    public function plan(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Plan::class,Client::class);
    }
    public function ubication(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Ubicacion::class,Client::class);
    }
    public function contacto(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Contacto::class,Client::class);
    }
    public function client(){
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}
```

**Client.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'nombre',
        'ruc',
        'status',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function contacto(){
        return $this->hasMany(Contacto::class);
    }
    public function feedback(){
        return $this->hasMany(Feedback::class);
    }
    public function plan(){
        return $this->hasMany(Plan::class);
    }
    public function ubication(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ubicacion::class);
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested data Eager Loading:
[Laravel Documentation Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```php
$user = User::find(1)
   ->with('clients', 'clients.contacto', 'clients.ubications', 'clients.plans')
   ->get();
In my case I want all products with a relationship It's work for me 
Product::where('id','>',1)->with('categories')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks sir , Really appreciate your help